# Excel power query : handle column containing both number and text /xlookup returns #REF upon refresh

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using power query to pull data for our sharepoint. I am having an issue with a column containg IDs which are a mix of whole numbers and texts. I need to use the column with xlook up to fill data to another spreadsheet. But the look up does not work as the numbers are also considered as text. Do you know how I can handle the data type in power query so that the number are acknowledged as number and the text as text?

Another thing, whenever I refresh the query my formula returns a reference error. Is there a way to avoid this happening?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please paste in powerquery code (from home..advanced...) and past in the formula producing the error otherwise we have no idea what you are doing.  If the data type in powerquery is any, then text appears as text and numbers as numbers when loaded into excel sheet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I was just able to solve this issue since I wasn't able to find the solution anywhere.

It happened after I altered PQ due to the database changing headers on me. After I was able to repair the PQ ever refresh resulted in a REF error for any xlookups on the PQ table.

I "rewrote" the xlookup code but copying it into notepad, removing the code from excel, then copying it back into excel. This for whatever reason worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32501219)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are matching IDs data from one source to another. I recommend that you force both sources of data to be type as text. This way when you are comparing both you end up with both being type as text.

Comment: I tried changing both as text, but end up with issues in Excel that lookup don't work. But I think I need to go a step further and get rid of having to use xlookup altogether.  Thanks for your answer 